# Build error on phonegap android

Tags: cordova

I've cretaed a new app and when I'm try to build appears error

```
executing command 'ant' make sure you have ant installed and added to your path
```

Comment: Can you please add some more information to your question? Important items that will help are: What Operating System are you on (and it's version), Which version of phonegap are you using, have you installed ant, do you have the android sdk installed (which version), how did you create the app (which commands did you use, or are you trying to build from an IDE). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Install [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi).

Note: zip archive binary version

Also, PhoneGap needs all its paths correctly specified for all the dependent sdks and platforms.

Add to your path some think like this:

```
Variable Name: JAVA_HOME Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: C:\Documents and Settings\Your Name\Application Data\npm;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: C:\Your Installation Path\To Node JS\

Variable Name: ANT_HOME Variable Value: C:\Your Path\To Ant\apache-ant-1.9.3;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: %ANT_HOME%\bin;

Variable Name: ANDROID_SDK_HOME Variable Value: C:\Location To\Your Work\Environment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: C:\Location To\Your Work\Environment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;

Variable Name: PATH Variable Value: C:\Location To\Your Work\Environment\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;
```

I hope it helps :)